# Three routers, one switch

Tags: networking, router, switch, local-area-network, fiber

I have a problem. The broadband ISP in my area is really unreliable, so I have decided to get an "Airfiber" subscription along with the one I have. The idea is to connect both routers' LAN ports to a single network switch, to which I will connect all the non-WiFi Deskop computers. I hope that this will allow the network to access the internet from both routers parallely, and allow all the computers to the still access the internet when any one router does not work. I want to know (in simple words) what extra configuration needs to be done for this to work.

The second part is that both these routers combined do not have enough of a device limit to satisfy the large number of Wi-Fi devices such as laptops and smartphones on the network. So if I connect the WAN port of yet another router (in WAP mode) to the swich from earlier, will it also use the other routers to access the internet and swich over whenever either one fails? Also I wish to know what extra configuration will be required here. I am a little concerned about IP addresses because all 3 routers are set to use 192.168 based IP addresses by default.

I am still a novice when it comes to networking, so it would be quite appreciated if you answer in simple words and guide me to youtube tutorials. :)

Comment: Your proposed solution won't work. You need some kind of router that can perform failover.